# Batch file that runs program works in batch mode but not though process start in dotnet core

Tags: batch-file, asp.net-core

I have a batch file that basically has just one line

```
myapp.exe file.dbm -calc
```

The exe creates a file in the same folder (depending on the input file file.dbm). That batch file runs on the server (Windows Server 2016), when I start it manually. Now I need to trigger it though web and created this dotnet core api

```
    public IActionResult get()
    {
        try
        {
            using (Process p = new Process { EnableRaisingEvents = true })
            {
                string batchFileLocation = @"C:\\folder\\startapp.bat";
                p.StartInfo.FileName = batchFileLocation;
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(batchFileLocation);
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
            return Ok("all good");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

The weird part is, it doesn't work BUT, when I change the bat like this (the first debugging that came into mind)

```
mkdir test1
myapp.exe file.dbm -calc
mkdir test2
```

both folders are being created in the correct location. But not the output of the exe. 
Why is that?

I can run the exe directly, but nothing happens

```
    public IActionResult get()
    {
        try
        {
            string batchFileLocation = "C:\\app\\myapp.exe";

            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = batchFileLocation;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:\\app\\file.dbm -calc";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            return Ok("no error");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Ok(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

There is no error, it just goes though without raising an error and the expected output file is not created.

**UPDATE**

If I install vs code on the server and just debug the application, everything works. 
I appears to be some sort of windows issue. In release on IIS it doesn't work, but in vs code in debug mode the same code runs fine. 
The main issue I have is, there is no error or anything, the try catch runs without exception.

Comment: `.exe` files don't require to be run from a scripted command line interface! why do you think that running a batch file is easier than running another executable file, with one or more arguments? Also, there's no need to deliberately omit information such as the real name, _(and version if necessary)_, of the `.exe` file, and the real option(s)/argument(s). It is not possible for data or security to be breached by supplying this information! Please revisit your question, and try to provide sufficient pertinent information for others to be able to replicate your issue, and potentially assist.

Comment: 1) I need to pass arguments and having a batch files makes it easier for me to change. That's why a batch
2) It's a custom app, you don't have it, so there is no use to give any other name
3) The real argument is `-input file.dbm`

Comment: It's no harder to run an executable as your process, with an option/argument, than it is to maintain a batch file along side that and modify that too! I can only assume that it is supposed to run `myapp.exe` and output whatever the secret code asks it to, to a file, _(`C:\folder\file.dbm`)_. I'll also assume that `C:\folder\file.dbm` is empty or doesn't exist upon completion, so the issue is with the app not the batch file or command. If I don't have the app, rst, and you cannot tell me exactly how it works, what it's supposed to output, and where, how am I supposed to provide any assistance?

Comment: The exe is a super old program and can be run with an input file `file.dbm`. Everything works perfectly when I just double click the batch file. The output-file is being created and the exe runs. I don't understand why everything in the batch file is being executed but not that particular line

Comment: Okay so where is the output supposed to go then? When you invoke a batch file directly, it is internally run as an argument to `cmd /c`. So your command being run is `cmd /c C:\folder\startapp.bat`. So technically you're now running `cmd.exe`, and passing it, the `/c` option together with the command `C:\folder\startapp.bat`, which is then running `myapp.exe` with the option `-input` and the argument `file.dbm`. That doesn't sound easier to me!

Comment: I updated the question. I tried to run it directly, but also that doesn't work. The biggest issue is, I don't know where to look

Comment: Okay, we're now an hour in, and you've changed your failing command from `myapp.exe -output argument` to `myapp.exe -output file.dbm` to `myapp.exe -input file.dbm` to `myapp.exe file.dbm -calc`. I think I'm going to step away from this until you know yourself what you're doing. And as it's still unclear and absolutely no debugging information has been supplied, I'm marking it for closure at this time. I'd advise you to please try harder to assist those people who may be willing to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215845/discussion-between-rst-and-compo).